# Excel 'Google search' code breaking randomly: Run Time error '91'

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, google-search

Here is my current code, found from multiple people on the Forum. Usually it will work fine for about 100 search results and then give me "Run Time Error '91'"
I'm beginning to think it has something to do with google and not the actual code too because its very randomly occuring
Thanks

```
Sub XMLHTTP()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 2 To lastRow

url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send

  Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  html.body.innerhtml = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
  Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

  numb_H3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3").Length
  If numb_H3 > 0 Then
  Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
  Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

  str_text = Replace(link.innerhtml, "<EM>", "")
  str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

  Cells(i, 2) = str_text
  Cells(i, 3) = link.href
  Else
  End If
  DoEvents

Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: Google tracks repetitious (aka *robotic*) searches and may randomly throw a Captcha to provide you are a human being. Approximately 100 searches sounds about right. If you dump the `html.body.innerText` to a file, the special Captcha page should be evident. Most search engines have some form of robotic search detection.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use if statement:

```
 If XMLHTTP.waitForResponse(WAIT_TIMEOUT) Then 'response ready
  Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  html.body.innerhtml = XMLHTTP.responseText
  Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

  numb_H3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3").Length
  If numb_H3 > 0 Then
  Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)
  Set link = objH3.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

  str_text = Replace(link.innerhtml, "<EM>", "")
  str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

  Cells(i, 2) = str_text
  Cells(i, 3) = link.href
  Else
  End If
  DoEvents
End If
```

Comment: That is what I read through, but it gives me an error with the 

numb_H3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3").Length
line... still run time error 91
 does the numb_h3 need to be 'Set'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, seems to be Google indeed. turning on VPN solves the issue, so there is nothing wrong with the code itself.